# WTelegramClient как получить последние 10 сообщений из чата?

Tags: c#, telegram

В документации не нашёл способа получения несколько сообщений, а не всех.
Пытался сам разобраться, но ничего не выходит.
Код с которым я пытался p.s не знаю выполняет ли он то, что я хочу. Никак не могу получить текст сообщения.

```
var chats = await client.Messages_GetAllChats(null);
InputPeer peer = chats.chats[currentPeer];
int offset = 0;
 
var messages = await client.Messages_GetHistory(peer, 0, default, offset, 1000, 0, 0, 0);
for (int msgNumber = 0; msgNumber < 5; msgNumber++)
{
      Console.WriteLine(messages.Messages[msgNumber]);
}
```

На выходе получаю [image: вывод]

Код из документации, с помощью которого получаются все сообщения в корректном виде

```
var chats = await client.Messages_GetAllChats(null);
InputPeer peer = chats.chats[currentPeer]; // the chat we want
for (int offset = 0; ;)
{
       var messages = await client.Messages_GetHistory(peer, 0, default, offset, 1000, 0, 0, 0);
            foreach (var msgBase in messages.Messages)
               if (msgBase is Message msg)
                    Console.WriteLine(msg.message);
           offset += messages.Messages.Length;
       if (offset >= messages.Count) break;
}
```

Comment: Ну так вы получили объект `Message` в данной строке `messages.Messages[msgNumber]`, берите дальше с него нужные свойства, вон кодом ниже даже показано как `Console.WriteLine(msg.message);`. А вообще, не забывайте про отладку! Поставьте точку остановки на нужной строке, далее наведите на объект и смотрите что в нем находится.

Answer (score 0):

```
async void SubChanel(WTelegram.Client client)
{
    var resolved = await client.Contacts_ResolveUsername("mytbilisi_chat"); // without the @ https://t.me/mytbilisi_chat
    if (resolved.Chat is Channel channel)
        await client.Channels_JoinChannel(channel);
    long chatId = resolved.Chat.ID; // подписываемся на чат и получаем его id
    GetMessage(client, chatId);
}

async void GetMessage(WTelegram.Client client, long chat)
{
    var chats = await client.Messages_GetAllChats();
    InputPeer peer = chats.chats[chat];
    // 0 это оффсет для вывода последних 100 смс, 
    // если указать 1, будут показаны предпоследних смс
    var messages = await client.Messages_GetHistory(peer, 0);
    if (messages.Messages.Length < 100) return;
        var list = new List<string>();
    foreach (var msgBase in messages.Messages)
        {
            if (msgBase is Message msg)
            {
            list.Add(msg.message); // заполняем лист сообщениями
            if (list.Count() == 10)
                break;
            }
        }
}
```